# How to make user-commands in C++ to run a function?

Tags: c++, input, command

This may sound simple to answer, but I don't know how to make this work. I have a set of functions put together to control a line editor, but each function has a different effect on the line editor to do things.

Anyways, for example... I have a function called "setfilename". I want to make a command that a user has to input in order to call it with his specific filename.

For example, the command for "setfilename" to be called should be "r filename
" which stands for "read filename"

The user would have to input "r test" for a filename of test to be read.

Is this clear? How could I do this? There will be a list of commands I'd want that would call different functions each.

LIST:

```
string choice;

cout << "What command would you like to perform?" << endl;
cout << "r filename" << endl;
cout << "w filename" << endl;
cout << "q" << endl;
cout << "s n" << endl;
cout << "s m n" << endl;
cout << "i n" << endl;
cout << "l n" << endl;
cout << "d n" << endl;
cout << "d n m" << endl;
cout << "c n" << endl;
cout << "c n m" << endl;
cout << "p n" << endl;
cout << "P n" << endl;
cout << "f string" << endl;
cout << "F string" << endl;
cout << "x string1 string2" << endl; // bonus

while (true)
{

    cout << "INPUT: -> ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice=="r filename")
    {
        setfilename(choice)

    }

    else if (choice == "w filename")
    {

        ...
    }

    else if (choice == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }



}
```

Comment: and `std::getline()`

Comment: I want to type in "r test" for example, but I don't want my filename to be called r test. It should be "test". So your answer isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, it is the answer.  Call `std::getline()` in a loop.  It will give you a `std::string`.  Then you simply split up that value as needed, such as by using `std::string::find()` and `std::string::substr()`, and process the substrings as needed.  If you don't know how to do simply `string` parsing, then you need to stop what you are doing any go back to basics.  This is a fundamental skill of C++.

Comment: You could read in just the command first, check its value to see what the command is and then read in its parameters because different commands have different numbers and types of parameters.

Comment: Use a lookup table or `std::map` with function pointers or function objects.  Use the character as the key or index field.  Search for the function pointer associated with the character, then dereference the pointer to execute the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop needs to look more like this instead:

```
while (true)
{
    cout << "INPUT: -> ";
    getline(cin, choice);

    istringstream iss(choice);
    iss >> choice;

    if (choice == "r")
    {
        iss >> choice;
        setfilename(choice);
    }
    else if (choice == "w")
    {
        iss >> choice;
        ...
    }
    else if (choice == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::getline()` and parsing (sub-)strings using a `std::istringstream` would be more appropriate and concise IMHO.

Comment: πάντα has a point - in the original code `choice` is a `std::string`, so you'll need to use `getline` to get the whole line with which to construct `iss`.